# Android Camera2 preview and capture with 4:3 aspect ratio but width > height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to achieve a custom size camera view (preview and capture) with Camera2 api. In particular a 4:3 ratio but landscape preview (width > height).

So far I am able to get correct TextureView size but the preview is squeezed vertically, or correct preview but TextureView size goes beyond required container size.

Tried setting a `SCALER_CROP_REGION` with below code but no effect.

```
val sensorRect = cameraCharacteristics
    .get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE)
    ?: return@run

val sensorWidth = sensorRect.width()

val sensorToViewRatio = sensorWidth / preview.width.toFloat()

val sensorBottom = (preview.height * sensorViewRatio).roundToInt() + sensorRect.top

previewRequestBuilder.set(
    CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION,
    Rect(sensorRect.left, sensorRect.top, sensorRect.right, sensorBottom)
)
```

Also tried `textureView.setTransform(matrix)` with `setRectToRect` and `postScale` but no luck. That cropped the preview surface itself but the actual preview is still squeezed.

What is the correct and recommended way of achieving this kind of custom preview and capture size?

I am woking on an enhanced version of [google's CameraView library](https://github.com/google/cameraview).

The library [CameraViewEx](https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex) codebase that I am working on can be found [here](https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex).

Below are the classes that might be relevant to achieve intended behaviour.

- [CameraView container](https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex/blob/master/cameraViewEx/src/main/java/com/priyankvasa/android/cameraviewex/CameraView.kt)
- [TextureView](https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex/blob/master/cameraViewEx/src/main/java/com/priyankvasa/android/cameraviewex/TextureViewPreview.kt)
- [Camera2 implementation](https://github.com/pvasa/cameraview-ex/blob/master/cameraViewEx/src/main/api21/com/priyankvasa/android/cameraviewex/Camera2.kt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCALER_CROP_REGION will not change the aspect ratio of output.  The main developer docs don't make it as clear as possible, but there are a few diagrams [here](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_crop_reprocess) that show how the cropping happens.

Image sensors are required to line up with the long side of the device, so a device held in landscape will easily display a landscape preview.  So are you asking about a portrait UI layout with a landscape-aspect ratio View showing camera preview?

In general, you can't do that without either adding black bars to preview (in this case, on the left and right), or you crop and zoom (removing a large percentage of the field of view; about 45% for 4:3 aspect ratio).

The latter should be possible via TextureView's transform, but you have to make sure you start with the transform already set on the TextureView, or you have to take into account more transforms involving the relative orientations of the sensor, device, and UI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am trying to get a landscape aspect ratio in a portrait layout.

"Image sensors are required to line up with the long side of the device" That explains the portrait outputs that I am getting currently. Is it described in detail somewhere? 

Also what do you mean by "make sure you start with the transform already set on the TextureView"? Do you mean before `captureSession.startRepeating(..)`?

Comment: When you connect a camera device to a TextureView Surface, the device sets a transform on the TextureView (visible via TextureView.getTransform once you have images flowing).  If you override that transform, you'll lose out on some orientation adjustments the camera did for you, unless you start with the transform provded by getTransform().

The long-side-of-device requirement is in the Android CDD: https://source.android.com/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd.html#7_5_5_camera_orientation .